# What is FarmWarDeployer?

Tags: tomcat

What is FarmWarDeployer in the  I have used that in the session Replication I onl know that webapplication is deployed in one place and I couldnot get that how to use it ? I am using tomcat6 in Linux/Debian machine.
Some one can help to proceed it further.

 thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A farm war deployer is a class that is able to deploy/undeploy web applications in WAR form within the cluster. Any host can act as the admin, and will have three directories
- *deployDir - the directory where they watch for changes*
- *applicationDir - the directory where they install applications*
- *tempDir - a temporaryDirectory to store binary data when downloading a war from the cluster*
Currently they only support deployment of WAR files since they are easier to send across the wire.

You can get more info here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/cluster/deploy/FarmWarDeployer.html